Null hypotheses of two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov, two-sample Anderson-Darling, and (two-sample) Wilcoxon rank sum test
As far as I understand, the null hypothesis $H_0$ of both two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test and the two-sample Anderson-Darling (AD) is the same, i.e. that two samples come from the same distribution/population.
Can we say that the null hypothesis $H_0$ of the (two-sample) Wilcoxon rank sum (WRS) test is the same of the KS and AD tests, with just the "additional condition" that the medians of the two samples should be identical?

It's no more and no less the null hypothesis than it is for the two sample t-test.

Thanks @Glen_b, I guess you refer to the $H_0$ of the Wilcoxon rank sum test..?

Yes. Some people seem to put the assumption of exchangeability into the hypothesis rather than the assumptions, but it makes no more sense to do that than it does to put "normality" into the null of the t-test. Its not what you're using the rank sum test to test, but specifically a change in P(A>B) from 1/2; exchangeability is just the condition under which you can compute the null distribution of the test statistic.

thanks :-) ...However, still a small doubt... from here https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/the-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test#:~:text=Whereas%20the%20null%20hypothesis%20of,distribution%20with%20the%20same%20median.
I read
Whereas the null hypothesis of the two-sample t test is equal means, the null hypothesis of the Wilcoxon test is usually taken as equal medians. Another way to think of the null is that the two populations have the same distribution with the same median.

Then, to my understanding, we can say the following.
$H_0$ of KS: null is that the two samples have the same distribution,
$H_0$ of AD: null is that the two samples have the same distribution,
$H_0$ of WRS: null is that the two samples have the same distribution, with the same median. Right or wrong?

The equal medians is a whole different issue that is covered by many answers on site. The test certainly doesn't test equality of medians unless you add assumptions that would make it a test of say equality of means just as well.

Thanks... However I read in several places that the null of the WRS test is that the two samples have the same distribution, with the same median ...so i dont understand your comments about medians... I mean the null of WRS is about the medians as well... :-)

If two distributions are truly identical then they necessarily have the same median. This page has a couple of very good answers specifically about KS vs WRS tests (including one from @Glen_b ). If the two underlying continuous distributions from which you sampled are members of a family that can differ only by a shift in location, then you can treat WRS as a test on medians.

Thanks a lot @EdM!! Your comment and links clarify a lot

@Ommo While under the assumptions they have the same median under H0, that doesn't make the rank sum test a test of medians. Consider that under the alternative I can hold the medians constant while changing what the test does test for, and get a rejection with identical sample (and population) medians, because the test detects something other than a difference in medians. Just because you find a link that says something doesn't make it so - many books, including some that are highly popular among nonstatisticians - get details of tests wrong, especially with nonparametric tests

An example of a suitable null and alternative with a two-tailed rank sum test for continuous variables  is $H_0: P(X>Y)=\frac12$ vs $H_1: P(X>Y)\neq\frac12$. There are other ways to write it that mean essentially the same thing (and you need to write something slightly more general for non-continuous variables, but I don't want to overcomplicate the explanation. This phrasing avoids the issues I just mentioned above

Many thanks @Glen_b, I very appreciate your explanation. About books and articles (about statistics), I found "everything and its opposite", so it is difficult to judge things if you are not an experienced statistician (who I am not)... Thanks :-)

The null for a 2-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (KS) is that the 2 samples come from exactly the same distribution; a KS test of $N(0,1)$ against $N(1,1)$ will be significant (for adequate sample sizes).
The null for a 2-sample Anderson-Darling test (AD) is exactly the same. But it has been shown that AD is more powerful at detecting differences, particulalry when the differences are only in the tails (same mean, same variance). E.g. see this paper.
The statistics for both KS and AD are fundamentally based on the ECDF, so indeed are based on the distribution function. Both tests are non-parametric.
The 2-samples Wilcoxon Rank Sum test (WRS, aka Mann-Whitney U test - MWU) is a very different beast. It is also a non-parametric test. The null is that $P(A>B)=P(B>A)$, meaning the probability that a random value from A is  greater than a random value from B is the same as a random value from B being greater than a random value from A. That is, neither distribution is stochastically greater than the other. This null (sometimes also written as $P(A>B)+ \frac 1 2 P(A=B)>\frac 1 2$) requires no assumption. Now, if you make additional assumptions, you can turn MWU into a test of same distribution. That assumption is that at least 1 sample comes from a non-symmetrical distribution. Unfortunately, that assumption is not really testable; yes, if a sample is very skewed, you can feel pretty comfortable, but in other cases...
Take, as a counter-example, sample A being drawn from $N(0,1)$, and sample B being a mixture (equal proportions) of $N(-5,1)$ and $N(5,1)$. They are both symmetrical. MWU will never be significant (except for $\alpha$ errors), but the 2 distributions are very different. Btw, KS or AD would find a difference (assuming appropriate sample size/power).
So, if the 2 distributions are symmetrical, WRS aka MWU can not tell any difference. If one is symmetrical but not the other, you do not need any test, they are obviously different. And if they are both non-symmetrical, then MWU tells you whether one distribution is stochastically greater than the other (which is very different than telling you whether they come from the same distribution). If the test is significant, clearly you can tell that the distributions are different; but otherwise??? You may find this article interesting in this respect. ANd making assumptions about the median does not help the MWU test become a test of distribution.
Note that the statistics for WRS or MWU are based on either the sum of ranks, or on the counts of all possible pair-wise comparisons, and so are not fundamentally about the distribution function(s).
So one really should not use a 2-sample MWU to test for equal distribution.
TLDR; KS and AD tests is suitable to detect any kind of difference between 2 distributions. 2-sample AD is found to be superior to KS, both having the same null (same distribution). WRS (aka MWU) is a different test alltogether, with a different null; it was specifically constructed to test whether one distribution is stochastically smaller or larger than the other. AD is the better test to compare 2 distributions.

Thanks a lot @jginestet, very appreciated! A very nice answer :-) About the Engmann & Cousineau (2011) paper, I knew about it, and it is one of my main references :-) Also the Hart (2001) paper is interesting (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1120984/pdf/391.pdf)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19694/356567
That is a nice answer about the Wilcoxon rank sum test, which supports/strengthens your (already nice) answer :-)

Given: (1) the @David Smith answer (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/275868/356567), i.e. "Under the null hypothesis the Mann-Whitney assumes that the two distributions are the same. The alternative that is tested for is that one distribution is stochastically greater than the other", and, (2), your answer, in particular "Wilcoxon Rank Sum test (WRS, aka Mann-Whitney U test - MWU) is a very different beast. The null is that $P(A>B)=P(B>A)$", I deduce that (3) the null "$P(A>B)=P(B>A)$" means "that the two distributions are the same".

And (4), the alternative that "$P(A>B)\neq P(B>A)$" means "one distribution is stochastically greater than the other".

I also found the Karch (2021) paper (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/2515245921999602), where he mentions the Fay & Proschan (2010) paper (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20414472/) in Section "Multiple perspectives on the
Mann-Whitney test". He lists the following: (1) "Equality of distributions - Null hypothesis: Population distributions are equal in all aspects", (2) "_Equality of medians

Null hypothesis: Population medians are
equal_", and (3) "_Stochastic equality
Null hypothesis: $P(X>Y) = P(Y>X)$_". Therefore, it looks like there are several interpretations


@Ommo, MWU will fail at finding 2 symmetrical distribution different (like the example I gave in my answer). So it does not really test for "same distribution". Yes, if the MWU is significant, then you can obviously conclude "not the same". But if it is not significant, you do not know what to conclude.  Wrt to Fay's paper,  the problem with their perspectives is that they depend on F & G belonging to a subset of distributions for which the perspective is valid; with that sleight of hand, I could justify any perspective on any test (e.g. say that the t-test is a test of medians).

...ctd. And the assumptions for ensuring F & G belong to the proper subset are not testable (certainly not reliably). In addition, the MWU test is not at all well behaved when the assumption is broken (contrary, say, to the t-test, which is well behaved to non-extreme departures from normality, because of the CLT). So I wouild not recommend using MWU for anything else than stochastic ordering. Btw, thanks for the links.

Thanks for your comment :-) Maybe, but just an opinion.....a safe "choice", at this point, would be to consider the null of MWU as the "stochastic equality", i.e. to use MWU only to for "stochastic equality".... and if MWU is significant you can say that "one distribution is stochastically dominant over the other", and if MWU is not significant, well, as you said, you can not conclude anything... thanks to you for your comments and answer :-)

@Ommo, your last comment was spot on... One (very minor) comment; use "stochastic superiority" rather than "stochastic dominance". Some field (econometrics and others) have defined "stochastic dominance" (see wiki), and it is not what MWU tests. So several folks get upset when one uses stochastic dominance in the context of MWU. Hence I am always careful to only use stochastic superiority (or inferiority), or stochastically greater/smaller, etc...

Thanks, really appreciated! I will follow your suggestions :-)

Sorry for writing again... but I was reading the paper of
Mann & Whitney (1947), On a Test of Whether one of Two Random Variables is Stochastically Larger than the Other and I noticed these statements:
[First] "2. Introduction. Let x and y be two random variables having continuous
cumulative distribution functions f and g respectively. The variable x will be
called stochastically smaller than y if f(a) > g(a) for every a. We wish to test
the hypothesis f = g against the alternative that x is stochastically smaller than
y. S" and

[Second] "5. Consistency of the U test. If f and g are the cumulative distribution functions of the x's and y's then our null hypothesis is f = g",
[Third]
"The test is shown to be consistent with respect to the class of alternatives
f(x) > g(x) for every x."

Therefore, according to their paper, the null of the MWU test is that the CDFs of the (two distributions of those) two samples are the same, and the alternative is that one CDF is stochastically larger/smaller than the other one.... Therefore the null and the alternative refer to the CDFs of the two samples (through the calculation of the "mean ranks" or the "sum ranks").... Or better to say, they refer to the ECDFs of the two samples.

If everything is correct and makes sense, then the MWU's null hypothesis of "stochastic equality" should refer to the "null hypothesis is F = G" i.e. to the two ECDFs being identical. No need to reply, but it was just to deepen a bit this fascinating topic. :-)

@Ommo, your interesting reasoning is unfortunately disproven by simnple counterexamples; 2 symmetrical distributions (e.g. uniform and gaussian), of same mean will always be stochastically equal. MWU should fail to reject the null, even though the 2 distributions are different.  Moreover, if the null is F=G, then when you reject the null all you can say is $F  \ne G$, which does not inform you at all on what/how F is different from G. You need to then go back to "one is stochastically greater than the other" to be able to interpret rejection of the null. ...ctd

...ctd So why not start with a null of "F is stochastically equal to G", because this is where you will end up. The U statistic computes a stochastic superiority count, and does not compare PDF's or CDF's. MWU fails as a test of equal distributions for symmetrical distributions of equal means, and does not let you make decisions from a rejection of the null (is F better? or G?) unless you resort to the stochastic superiority property. So let's leave it as a test of stochastic superiority...

Thanks @jginestet :-) nice comments, thanks!
